# Why are the letters separated on the console?

Tags: command-line, fonts, budgie

I have Ubuntu Budgie 21.10 installed and Google's ProductSans font, everything looks fine except the console, what can I do to fix this and it can be seen fine on the console?

Console font not working:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Menu font working:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Interface font working:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Open Preferences in your terminal program (i.e. not console) and select some monospace font which looks good.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal, open preferences and on text tab decrease cell width spacing

[image: Terminal Properties]